# How to write the types explicitly on the left when the function returns multiple values?

Tags: go

I can do

```
n,err:=r.Read(b)
```

Also I can write

```
var n,err=r.Read(b)
```

But on the left I want the types explicitly, like (because this does not work),

```
var n,err int,error=r.Read(b)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this is having the variables declared before calling the function:

```
var n ini
var err error
n, err = r.Read(b)
```